# Why does this route logic not find already created documents and instead create new, duplicated ones?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I want insert a "channel" item named `X` into a `Mongo.Collection` when routing to a specific URL `/X`, but only when the Item named `X` is not found in the DB. Otherwise it should get the item from the DB and pass it as `data` to use it to render my `channelPage` template.

```
Channels = new Meteor.Collection('channels');

Router.route('/:channelName', {
  name: 'channelPage',
  template: 'channelPage',
  data: function() {
    var currentChannelName = this.params.channelName.toLowerCase();
    var channelInDB = Channels.findOne({
      name: currentChannelName
    });
    if (channelInDB === undefined) {
      Channels.insert({
        name: currentChannelName
      });
      return Channels.findOne({
        name: currentChannelName
      });
    } else {
      return channelInDB;
    }
  }
});
```

The `data` function seems to run twice every time I route to the `/X` page. The first time `(channelInDB === undefined)` is `true`. Even if there is already a "channel" item with `{name: "X"}` in the collection. So a new Item named `X` will be inserted every time I request the page.
Also tried to do the check in the `onBeforeAction` hook, didn't help.
What am I missing and how do I solve this issue?

---

**UPDATE**

I moved the `upsert` to `Meteor.methods` what I should have done in the first place. My code now looks like this:

```
Router.route('/:channelName', {
  name: 'channelPage',
  template: 'channelPage',
  data: function() {
    var currentChannelName = this.params.channelName.toLowerCase();
    var channelId = Meteor.apply('callChannelPage', [currentChannelName], {
      wait: true
    });
    console.log(channelId); //undefined
    return channelId;
  }
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    'callChannelPage': function(channelName) {
      Channels.upsert({name: channelName}, {$set: {name: channelName}});
      var result = Channels.findOne({name: channelName}, {fields: {_id: 1}});
      return result._id;
    }
  });
}
```

I used `Meteor.apply` with the `{wait: true}` option instead of `Meteor.call` to wait for the response but it still returns `undefined` at the time the route is running.
I know the `Meteor.method` works because when I run a `call` with `asyncCallback` it returns the right `ChannelId`.

```
Meteor.call('callChannelPage', currentChannelName, 
  function(error, results) {
    console.log(results); //tfdaczfnZgwycFDtv
  });
```

How to get it when the Router runs so I can use the data in the Template?

---

**SOLUTION**

My current solution is to get the channel-data in the `channelPage.helper` based on only the channelname.

```
Router.route('/:channelName', {
    name: 'channelPage',
    template: 'channelPage',
    data: function() {
        var channelName = this.params.channelName.toLowerCase();
        Meteor.call('callChannelPage', channelName);
        return {channelName: channelName};
    }
});

//isClient
Template.channelPage.helpers({
    'name': function() {
        return this.channelName;
    },
    'channelId': function(){
        return Channels.findOne({name: this.channelName})._id;
    },
});

//isServer
Meteor.methods({
    'callChannelPage': function(channelName) {
        Channels.upsert({name: channelName}, {$set: {name: channelName}});
    }
});
```

This way, the Template renders and the data from the collection appears a bit delayed. Thats fine for my purpose but is it the right approach?

Comment: Does this only happen when going directly to that URL? Or does it happen when you use `Router.go('channelPage', {channelName: 'X'})`?

What do your subscriptions look like for Channels?

Comment: Don't forget you can do [Collection.upsert](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/upsert) to automatically insert only if the document doesn't already exist. That will save you some code.

Comment: @challett `Router.go('channelPage', {channelName: 'X'})` works fine. But I need more data on the `channelPage` than `channelName`. Should I route every URL to `channelPage` and use `Template.channelPage.handers` to get the data?

Comment: @Jahx You can add more parameters as needed.  But I am not sure what you mean.  Could you add your subscriptions to the Channel collection to your question?  Anything that you return in the routers data function will be available in your template helpers under `this` .  I haven't tried returning anything besides an object in data.  How do you access the channelID from your helpers?

Comment: @challett At this time I make use of the `autopublish` and `insecure` packages. My current solution is to get the channel-data in the `channelPage.helper` based on only the channelname. (see update)